# Quickbooks Online Integration with Mule

Tags: mulesoft, anypoint-studio, quickbooks-online, mule4, mule-connector

I am trying to integrate Quickbooks online with Mule. So far, I can complete the OAuth dance and retrieve the access token via the HTTP connector using the authorization code configuration.
The steps followed include:

1. COnfiguring the HTTP Request connector for OAuth dance which includes
2. Added authorization, callback URL, token URL, and client credentials
3. Configured payload for saving the access and refresh tokens

To trigger the oauth flow , I hit the authorize URL which in return gives me the realmId and authorization code

To make subsequent requests to the APIs using the extracted token I need the realm ID as well but I am not able to extract that.
The realmId is returned in the initial call along with the authorization code in the payload but when the process happens through mulesoft, there is no way to capture it and without the realmId I cannot make requests to the API.

Following is the XML configuration for HTTP:

```
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_configuration" doc:name="HTTP Request configuration" doc:id="36a1c561-9498-4dbf-b323-5c726b20cb6a" >
    <http:request-connection protocol="HTTPS" host="sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com" port="443">
        <http:authentication >
            <oauth:authorization-code-grant-type externalCallbackUrl="http://localhost:8082/callback" localAuthorizationUrl="https://localhost:8082/login" authorizationUrl="https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2" clientId="ABNxxKq4xy1KWs1BteaIIAhY3NC7G5jg9YZg3h15Zf3waDdEja" clientSecret="5k5GxV3HIBtM7DRSQOqlBqtjWfg07tFNAFeW9EeJ" tokenUrl="https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer" localCallbackUrl="http://localhost:8082/callback" state="abc" scopes="com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting">
                <oauth:custom-parameter-extractors >
                </oauth:custom-parameter-extractors>
            </oauth:authorization-code-grant-type>
        </http:authentication>
    </http:request-connection>
</http:request-config>
```

I need a way to extract the realmId and set it dynamically instead of hardcoding.
[This is the first request which gets the auth code and realmId before token exchange[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70zpB.png)

[This is how realmId will be used in subsequent requests after token exchange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUGkG.png)

**It is to be noted that I am not manually saving and reusing any variables, it is all happening as part of the Mulesoft HTTP connector oauth config**

[Reference guide for oauth in Mulesoft](https://docs.mulesoft.com/http-connector/1.7/http-authentication)

Comment: Please share the HTTP requests, the payload returned that contains the realm Id and how is the realm Id expected to be used in the other requests.

Comment: @aled I have added the relevant pictures

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for code or logs in Stackoverflow. For flows copy the XML. Also how the application receives the realm I'd now?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I have added XML for the code part.

The application is receiving the realmId behind the scenes, along with the authorization code.
Once I make the authorize call an authorization code is generated, if after that point onwards I make a call to the relevant endpoint e.g sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/account(an example) then the token gets generated due to step 1 but because I am unable to capture the realmId which will be used in the call, I cannot do so. I have added a picture of how the realmId will be used

Comment: Thank you, the configuration is useful to understand the problem. The screenshot titled "This is how realmId will be used in subsequent requests after token exchange" is from a postman screenshot and is not very clear how it relates to application and the HTTP Request. I would remove it since your problem appears to really be that the real id is received during the OAuth dance internally by the HTTP connector and you can not access it. Currently the question is closed. If there are more reopen votes it will be possible to suggest an answer.

Comment: The screenshot is the internal request which is received and I captured it using inspect element in chrome.